# Подтверждение личности в Google play console (ввод имени на латинице)

Tags: google-play

При попытке пройти идентификацию столкнулся с проблемой. Нужно загрузить скан удостоверения личности и вписать имя как указанно в этом ул. В удостоверении у меня используется латиница, а поле в которое нужно ввести свои имя и фамилию требует чтобы я использовал кириллицу. Как с этим бороться?[image: Скрин из Гугл консол]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам на днях проходил верификацию. Используйте транскрипцию вашего имени и фамилии на русском языке. Например: Фарит Шакуров. (если это ваше действительное имя и совпадает с информацией на удостоверении.

Comment: Не станет ли это проблемой, ведь там написано, мол вводить точно так как на удостоверении?

Comment: @FaritShakurov не станет, ведь вам сказали написать на кириллице т.к эти данные будет проверять русскоязычный отдел Google.

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: Здравстуй, еще раз. Я  пытался снова пройти подверждение. После загрузки сканов, нужно заполнить адрес. У меня стоит страна Россия, хотя я не из России и на сколько я знаю везде у меня указана моя страна проживания (Азербайджан), в том числе и вплатежном профиле. Можно ли это как то исправить. В саппорт гугла обратился, но там только по почте и ответа пока никакого нет.  Спасибо

Comment: Россия указана в самом аккаунте, или в меню подтверждения личности? (которое на скриншоте)

Comment: Проблема была следующая. Пару лет назад у меня был канал на ютубе и я открывал платежный профиль. Первый блин как говориться комом, поэтому пришлось открывать второй. Про первый я благополучно забыл. На него при регестации в Плэй Консоль и открылся аккаунт, т.к. так этот профиль был не активирован, консоль требовала ее активировать, что конечно я сделать не мог. Решение - удалил через Саппорт открытый аккаунт и спустя 3 месяца долгих попыток открыть новый (причины уже другая история) я наконец то это сделал на праивльный плаежный профиль. Возможно кому то будет полезна эта инфа